# Error to display a firestore timestamp element in the React view

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm having a issue with Firestore and React. The problem happens when a try to get a timestamp from firestore and display it in the view.

This is my firestore document

[image: firestore document]

Well, I'm just trying to get all this fields and displayed them into my a random view. The fields email and name are working perfectly, but the field `registeredAt` is not. I'm using `useEffect` to get the information from firestore when the page renders and I put some console.log to test if the timestamp element from firestore is coming and it is. For some reason, the problem happens when I use the `setUserInfo` to get the firebase object. And it only happens with the timestamp element. Please, if you can help me I would be very pleased! Thank you all!

Here's my code

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { logoutUser, db } from '../../configs/firebase';
import { doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

const Home = () => {

  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserInformation = async () => {
      const docRef = doc(db, "users", currentUser);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const userData = docSnap.data();
        console.log(userData.registeredAt.toDate().toISOString().substring(0,10));
        setUserInfo(userData);
      } else {
        console.log("This document does not exists");
      }
    };

    getUserInformation();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <h1>Welcome {userInfo.email}!</h1>
      <div>
        If you are here, you are allowed to it, {userInfo.name}
      </div>
      <div>
        Date of register: {userInfo.registeredAt.toDate().toISOString().substring(0,10)}
      </div>
      <button onClick={logoutUser}>
        Logout
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

and this is the error showed in the console when the application crashes

[image]

It is important to notice that, if I comment the div where I try to show the timestamp, everything works nicely, that is, the other information from firestore is being caught property and showed in the display.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data is not yet there when your component is rendered. It is undefined till the fetching of the data completes hence you need to use optional chaining.

Namely, instead of

```
{userInfo.registeredAt.toDate().toISOString().substring(0,10)}
```

do

```
{userInfo?.registeredAt?.toDate().toISOString().substring(0,10)}
```